# converting a list of files to a hyphen separated list

Tags: shell, unix

Say I have a folder that contains the following files

```
stuff1001.f
stuff1002.f
stuff1003.f
...
stuff1099.f
```

I have a command that requires me to enter these files in a hyphen separated list such that

```
command.py -i stuff1001.f-stuff1002.f-stuff1003.f-...
```

How can I:

1. Have terminal just print out the full hyphen separated list so I can copy/paste it?
2. enter some code into the command that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following may help:

`ls -1 | tr '\n' '-'`

The `ls -1` (that's a dash **one**) command writes the name of each file in the current directory to a separate line.  The `tr '\n' '-'` command then translates each newline into a hyphen.  The end result is a hyphen-separated list of the files in the current directory.

Comment: try it w/o the "-1".   using ls into a pipe gives a line at a time.   the "-1" flag is only needed at the terminal.  so:   python -i $(ls stuff*.f | tr '\n' -)